# Django makemigrations error non-nullable field

Tags: django, django-models, django-database

> You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'list' to signup without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
>   Please select a fix:
>    1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows)
>    2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py

This is the error for the following code for `ArrayField`:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField
from django.db import models
class signup(models.Model):
    userid=models.CharField(max_length=10)
    password=models.CharField(max_length=10)
    list=ArrayField(models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True),size=5)
    score=models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must specify that `list` can be `null` in the database:

```
list=ArrayField(models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True), size=5, null=True)
```